# Simple Dynamic Text in outbound SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dynamic, sms

I've been sending SMS through ExactTarget for years, but we want to cater specific info to individuals with SMS. I know nothing about AMPscript, but if I could get help writing a very simple template, I would be most grateful!

Here's what I want:

> "Thank you for attending our meeting! Your assigned seat is _______."

Columns I use in the CSV file are "Subscriber Key", "Mobile Number", and "Locale." Can I create a new column "Seat" and have the dynamic text pull that data to send the seat number to each attendee?

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the SMS? If you are using mobile connect you can add attributes for personalization through contact builder. Then simply add the variable to the SMS message.

Comment: I am using mobile connect in ExactTarget (Salesforce). I have never used contact builder. Just set up Outbound texts through Mobile Connect. Can you explain how to add attributes for personalization?